# Save responses to a file in JMeter with PostProcessor

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I try to use following code in `JSR223 PostProcessor` to save response to `CSV` file in each iteration.

```
if(${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode(),)} == "200"){
    vars.put("response", prev.getResponseDataAsString());

    String res="${response}";
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("logresult.csv",true);
    fstream.write(res+"\n");
    fstream.close();    
}
```

I assume csv file should be created in same folder as jmx, but it isn't present after execution. I execute test in one thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `${}` syntax in JSR223 script as part of JMeter [best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

```
if(prev.getResponseCode() == "200"){
    String res=prev.getResponseDataAsString();
    vars.put("response", res);
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("logresult.csv",true);
    fstream.write(res+"\n");
    fstream.close();    
}
```

> ensure the script does not use any variable using `${varName}` as caching would take only first value of `${varName}`. Instead use :
> `vars.get("varName")`

Comment: First of all csv file is not updated with variable value. Value is updated in each iteration. Is it possible to get also Sampler result tab to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not correct, you need to amend the first line to look like:

```
if(prev.getResponseCode().equals('200')){
```

also you don't need this line at all

```
String res="${response}";
```

instead use the following:

```
fstream.write(vars.get('response')+"\n");
```

see [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) for comprehensive explanation, the relevant quote:

> JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, so the references will only be resolved once. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error.

---

In general you're going into wrong direction, in case if you run your test with > 1 thread you might run into the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) when 2 threads will be writing into the same file resulting in garbage if not worse.

If you have to store the responses into a separate file I would recommend:

1. Extracting the whole response into a JMeter Variable using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
2. Defining [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property to hold this value
3. Write the value into the file using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

Comment: It doesn't write anything. I try to use FileWriter with `FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()+"\\logresult.csv"` , but has same effect, file isn't updated.

Comment: @Dmitri T: Please suggest best way to achieve data write to a single file when running with large number of threads in Jmeter

Comment: I would go for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer)